# Difference between "PIXI.Texture.from()" and "new PIXI.Texture()" in pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js, sprite-sheet

I am working on getting some textures assigned to an animatedSprite object in Pixi.JS

The below code works as expected:

```
\\ previously loaded: APP.loader.add("tile_sheet", "img/tile_spritesheet.png");

const texture_base = PIXI.BaseTexture.from(APP.loader.resources["tile_sheet"].url);
const texture_1 = new PIXI.Texture(texture_base); 
const component = PIXI.AnimatedSprite.from(texture_1);
```

However the following throws a "unrecognized source" error.

```
\\ previously loaded: APP.loader.add("tile_sheet", "img/tile_spritesheet.png");

const texture_base = PIXI.BaseTexture.from(APP.loader.resources["tile_sheet"].url);
const texture_1 = PIXI.Texture.from(texture_base); 
const component = PIXI.AnimatedSprite.from(texture_1);
```

My question is why does the second example *[which uses PIXI.Texture.from() rather than "new PIXI.Texture()"]* fail? Docs state Texture.from() should be able to accept a base texture as a source. In many of the tutorials the two syntaxes appear (confusingly) to be used interchangeably.

Comment: which version of Pixi.js?

Comment: using Pixi v6.1.2

Comment: it seems you are right - `PIXI.Texture.from(` doesnt really accept BaseTexture. You should add new "issue" in official Pixi.js repo: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues

Comment: thanks for verifying I am not crazy. I spend way too much time thinking it is just me.